# How to read a csv file having #

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I want to read from a `csv` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{initial.csv}
\end{document}
```

Now my `initial.csv` file looks like this:

```
a, # b 
1, 3
```

It creates the following errors:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \csv@col@body \csvautotabular{initial.csv}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \csv@temp \csvautotabular{initial.csv}
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode \csvautotabular{initial.csv}
```

Then I tried with replacing `#` by `\#`. It gives:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted \csvautotabular{initial.csv}
Extra \endcsname \csvautotabular{initial.csv}
File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@temp
```

Any idea on how should I try if my `csv` file contains some `#`'s?

Comment: ``{\catcode`#=12 \csvautotabular{initial.csv}}``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @wipet wrote, the problem is the catcode of the `#` sign. With the recent version `1.12 (2014/07/14)` of `csvsimple`, you can neutralize the `#` sign with the `respect sharp` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular[respect sharp]{initial.csv}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

There are some more `respect xy` options which also may be interesting for other use cases, e.g. `respect and` (for `&`) and `respect dollar` (for `$`).